# Oracle SQL can't select my indexes

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I created indexes like this:

```
--CREATE INDEXES for Tables
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX worker_name_index ON WORKER (worker_id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX company_name_index ON COMPANY (company_name);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX project_name_index ON PROJECT (project_id);
```

But cant find where the indexes are:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_INDEXES;
```

Also not here:

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_INDEXES;
```

nor here:

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_INDEXES;
```

And also cant drop these indexes, because dropping throws ORA-01418:specified index does not exist error.

```
--REMOVE INDEXES
DROP INDEX project_name_index;
DROP INDEX company_name_index;
DROP INDEX project_name_index;
```

and can't recreate, because creation rise ORA-01408:such columnt in list already indexed error...

Edited (with select * all_ind_columns and the index is not there)

[image]

Comment: you mean you get an error on dropping and an error on recreating (already exists)? your DDL that you've posted is not valid as you have an extra "index" keyword in there.

Comment: yes, exactly. And i mean also that i can't list my index with a select.. But somehow it is "live" somewhere because also can't recreate it with the same name... I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: No, it's not more clear now. Why don't you show us *everything*? **Including** the error message you get (and the real statement you are running - as the one in the question is invalid as DazzaL pointed out).

Comment: thanks guys, you have right, thats because i modified the query when i copy to here, but no i will edit to containt the origin queries.

Comment: So which `create` generates the ORA-01408?

Comment: Are you really sure the `create` statements ever worked with those exact names - you didn't ever have them wrapped in double-quotes, for example? You can see which indexes already exist with something like 'select index_name from all_ind_columns where table_name = 'WORKER' and column_name = 'WORKER_ID'`.

Comment: edited, i hope now clear.

Comment: I am sure it is worked, if you mean working that it was not generating error. But not a big deal, i can recreate it with other name at test again the issue... And so bad this query result also doesn't contain my indexes in the result :  (

Comment: If somehow i can select my indexes, i think i can get the names...
Update: Ok, this query (thanks Alex) really show shows the indexes:
select * from all_ind_columns where table_name = 'WORKER' and column_name = 'WORKER_ID'... INDEX_NAME: 'SYS_C0011015' Two question:
1) Why can't i seee this when i simply select * from all_ind_columns?
2) what's with this name? Why is this the name rather of 'worker_name_index'

Comment: It will be there if you `select * from all_ind_columns`, but I would think it would be hard to spot. The name suggests it's been automatically created as a unique constraint, or more likely primary key, as part of the `create table`, without you specifying a constraint name at that point. (See [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/clauses002.htm): 'If you do not specify a constraint name, then Oracle generates a system name for the constraint of the form SYS_Cn').

Comment: thanks!
believe me, it is not here in the "select * from all_ind_columns" : ( i will take a screenshoot, this issue seems to me weird and more magically from minute to minute...

Thank for the document, this worker_id trully my primary key

Comment: Your screenshot only shows the first 27 rows returned by the query. How many there will be depends on what you're using the DB for, but I suspect the `1151` on the status bar indicates that's how many rows are in the full resultset. Also, it is is a really bad idea to do anything like this as `SYS`, that is an internal Oracle account and you can really do a lot of damage...

Comment: Yeah, you have absolutely right about your comment, about roles, but it is my DB, so i train myself now and practice:)...
And sorry but i need to disagree 115 is only counting the row where my cursor is at the editor, and 1 is the column... And i tried with rownumber (to maximize the select) but can't get succed...

Comment: @horse_with_no_name: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX worker_name_index ON WORKER (worker_id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX company_name_index ON COMPANY (company_name);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX project_name_index ON PROJECT (project_id);

All of these creation make the error!

Comment: OK, the `1151` was a guess from trying to read small numbers on the screenshot. I don't use PL/SQL Developer, but according to [this site](http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/plsqldeveloper-setup-1.html) 'y default, one screenful of rows will be displayed in the result grid, with the size varying according to the amount of space that happens to be available', which seems to be what you're seeing. There is no way `SYS` only has 27 indexed columns; try doing a `count(*)` of that table.

Comment: Yeah, again right : / count result is 7k row : /... Anyway you can open in new tab the picture and i would be OK... Myself also not a PL/SQL developer user, and it works pretty else at mysql workbrench, this "feature" cos me a lot of headache... You spare me again some time... Thanks, this way maybe my indexes can also be found...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems to be a little misleading as you won't ever have been able to successfully create those named indexes. As shown by your subsequent queries against `all_ind_columns`, such as:

```
select * from all_ind_columns
where table_name = 'WORKER' and column_name = 'WORKER_ID'
```

... system-generated indexes already exist for the columns you are trying to index. The names (e.g. `SYS_C0011015`) indicate that they are system-generated backing indexes for primary key (or possibly unique) constraints defined against the tables.

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/clauses002.htm) notes in several places:

> If you do not specify a constraint name, then Oracle generates a
>   system name for the constraint of the form SYS_Cn.

So you can't have created the named indexes; if the constraints already existed on the tables then you'd always have got an ORA-01408, and if you'd tried to add the constraints after the indexes were created then the `alter` would have failed. Since they really don't exist it's quite reasonable that they aren't listed in `all_indexes` and cannnot be dropped, and you can't recreate them for the same reason you can't have created them in the first place...

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. And that was the reason, why i could make the index on the company_name row, which was not a primary key...

Answer (score 0):

Probably you created the index with a different oracle user than the user you use for dropping or selecting this index.

Comment: Unfortunatly not, i am using the same oracle user (sysdba).